# Calculated column based on previous column

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a table A as

```
amount numeric,
serial int,
due_date date,
rate numeric,
mi numeric
```

Sample Data:

```
amount.   rate.  due_date       mi.     serial
100000.   0.012.  '2017-01-01'   3000.    1
100000.   0.012.  '2017-02-01'   3000.    2
100000    0.012.  '2017-03-01'.  2000.    3
.
.
.
```

The amount column and rate are constant across rows.

I want to constuct a view for each row of the table as:

```
serial  opening      int_amount.  prncpl_amount.         prncpl_os
1.      amount          opening*0.012    mi-int_amount.   opening-prncpl_amount
2. previous(prncpl_os)  opening*0.012.   mi-int_amount.    opening-prncpl_amount       
.
.
```

I have tried using lag function, but since prncpl_os does not exist, it fails.

EDIT 1: The desired result would be

```
serial.    opening.    int_amount.    prncpl_amount.  prncpl_os
1.         100000.      1200           1800          98200
2.         98200.       1178.40.       1821.60.      96378.40
3.         96378.40.    1156.54.       843.46.       95534.94
```

EDIT 2: The calculation mistake was corrected as pointed...

Comment: can you also share the desired result to make clearer...

Comment: ..and what is stopping you from writing a query?

Comment: How to get value of previous prncpl_os @KaushikNayak Perhaps you may suggest.

Comment: Are you sure about the value 1180.54 for int_amount on the third line ?

Comment: 96378.4 * 0.012 = 1156.5408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT) for this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d1dc4e6f0d6c06115e253ab43edf54fb)

```
WITH RECURSIVE next_ser AS (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        lead(serial) OVER (ORDER BY serial) as next_serial
    FROM a
),
cte AS (

    SELECT
        serial,
        next_serial,
        amount AS opening,
        amount * rate AS int_amount,
        mi - (amount * rate) AS prncpl_amount,
        amount - mi + amount * rate AS prncpl_os
    FROM
        next_ser
    WHERE serial = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        a.serial,
        a.next_serial,
        c.prncpl_os,
        c.prncpl_os * a.rate,
        a.mi - (c.prncpl_os * rate),
        c.prncpl_os - mi + c.prncpl_os * rate
    FROM next_ser a
    JOIN cte c ON a.serial = c.next_serial
)
SELECT 
    serial, opening, int_amount, prncpl_amount, prncpl_os
FROM cte
```

1. The `next_ser` CTE is for calculating the next serial (in case they are not really consecutive) with help of the [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which gets the values from the next records.
2. The recursion is straight-forward: The non-recursive part (the first `SELECT` statement of the `UNION`) is the starting point, which calculates your first row. The second part of the `UNION` is the recursive part of the CTE. Within that the last recursion step (`JOIN cte`) is joined against the row which has the `serial` id which equals the `next_serial` of the last recursion step. The previous `prncpl_os` value can be taken to be calculated with the current values...

Comment: Although a recursive CTE is not needed for this, I think that is the simplest way to implement the logic.

Comment: Thanks, your answer solves the question posted....In reality the table has a column with client code. the sample was for one client. When adding 'and a.client_code = c.client_code' to join in cte has not worked. Am sure I will be able to do it. Thanks once more....

Comment: So,with addition of column client_code, it went into a cyclical relationship...last serial number had next serial as 1(from next client code.). Just needed to put a partition on lead(serial) to get a null value on the last serial.